# Export react native stackNavigator after checking for value in AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, navigation, stack-navigator

I have an application where a token get stored once the users open the app for the first time, and I need to check for that token when the app starts and create the navigator,

Approach 1

```
const getValue = async () => {
    try {
        value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((value) =>{
           console.log(value)
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
};

if (token != undefined) {
    stackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
        Products: Products,
        Product: Product
    }, {
        headerMode: 'none',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerVisible: false
        }
    })
} else {
    stackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
        Home:Home,
        Products: Products,
        Product: Product
    }, {
        headerMode: 'none',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerVisible: false
        }
    })
}
```

In the first approach, it always renders the home screen even if the token is stored in the application

Second approach

```
const getValue = async () => {
    try {
        value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((value) =>{
            if(value == null){
                stackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
                    Home:Home,
                    Products: Products,
                    Product: Product
                }, {
                    headerMode: 'none',
                    navigationOptions: {
                        headerVisible: false
                    }
                })
            }else{
                stackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
                    Products: Products,
                    Product: Product
                }, {
                    headerMode: 'none',
                    navigationOptions: {
                        headerVisible: false
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
};
```

This approach throws `Cannot read property of router undefined`

Is there a way to get this to work?

Navigation.js

```
export const getValue = async () => {
    let VALUE;
  try {

      await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
      .then((value) =>{
          if(value == null){
            VALUE = stackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
                  Home:Home,
                  Products: Products,
                  Product: Product
              }, {
                  headerMode: 'none',
                  navigationOptions: {
                      headerVisible: false
                  }
              })
          }else{
            VALUE =  stackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
                  Products: Products,
                  Product: Product
              }, {
                  headerMode: 'none',
                  navigationOptions: {
                      headerVisible: false
                  }
              })
          }
      })
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
  }

 return VALUE;

};
```

App.js

```
import { getValue } from './layout/navigation/Navigation';
let Navigation = createAppContainer(getValue());
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (<Navigation/>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Routing

```
stackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home:Home,
    Products: Products,
    Product: Product,
    Login : Login
  }, 
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName : 'Home',  // provide initial route : app will open with Home page 
    navigationOptions: {
        headerVisible: false
    },
})

 // Export it with createAppContainer 
 export default createAppContainer(stackNavigator);
```

Import it to your App.js and use it as `<Router/>`

```
import Router from 'Application/navigation/routes';
```

Now what you can do is when user going to login then store their token to AsyncStorage and then redirect to home page.

In your home page you can add your token is exist or not code in mount lifecycle if you are not getting your token from storage then you can navigate your route to login screen.

Comment: I tried but im getting an error saying getStateForAction is undefined, i added the complete code with the changes to the question